# Make a number divisible by another number but with floats?

Tags: java, math

I have a random number that's suppose to fit into 360.0f. My problem is my function only works for ints. How would I make another number fit into another one evenly up or down (preferably closest)

How would I make this work with floats?

Here's what I've got:

```
public static float fitNumberEvenlyIntoAnother(int number, int numberToFitInto)
{
    while(numberToFitInto % number != 0)
    {
        number += 1;

        if(Math.abs(number / 2f) > Math.abs(numberToFitInto))
        {
            Log.w("fitNumberEvenlyIntoAnother", "Oh ow, the fitNumberEvenlyIntoAnother has surpassed the number it's suppose to fit into");
        }
    }

    //This number needs to fit into the number evenly. Cannot be null or nan.
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Since you're using `360.0` I assume `number` is an angle and should be adjusted into range `[0,360[`, e.g. `410 degrees should be 50 degrees`. Is that correct? If not, could you give examples on input and expected output?

Comment: That is correct but I intent to use the function more than once for different ranges.

Comment: Surely all you need is the % operator? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "adjust" a number `x` into a range `r` (e.g. an angle into `[0,360[`), then you could do the following:

```
double len = r.max - r.min; 
double frac = x/len - Math.floor(x/len);     
double result = frac < 0 ? r.min + len * (1 + frac) :  r.min + len * frac;
```

What yo do is the following:

- you get the size of the range as `len` (`360 - 0 = 360` in the case of degrees)
- you calculate `len/(x % len)`
- if the fraction is negative you add 1
- the result is the lower bound of the range plus the fraction (in range `[0,1]`) of the range's length

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping on the *result*, just test if the result of division is a whole number:

```
public static float fitNumberEvenlyIntoAnother(float number, float numberToFitInto) {
    float result = numberToFitInto / number;
    if (result == Math.round(result))
        return result;
    return Float.NaN;
}
```

You haven't indicated what should be returned if it doesn't fit evenly - this impl returns the [*not a number*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN) value - you may want to do something different.

Comment: It needs to return a number, that number can decrease or increase until it fits into the numberToFitInto.